# mysql get number of summed rows

Tags: mysql, sum

Trying to select the combined amount of player scores in a clan other than your own, to determine your clans ranking.

The amount of rows it returns (greater than your clans score) is your clans position. If it returns 3 rows, then your clan is fourth.

My sql (doesnt work):

```
SELECT sum(score) as sum_score
FROM players WHERE sum_score  > " .$our_clan_score . " 
AND clan !=0 AND clan != $our clan 
GROUP BY clan
```

## `players` table

```
id    name    score    clan
------------------------------
4     Bill    455      2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be (can`t check)

```
SELECT sum(score) as sum_score
FROM players WHERE  clan !=0 AND clan !=  ".$our_clan."  
GROUP BY clan
HAVING sum_score  > " .$our_clan_score . "
```